# Perforce client missing files that are on the HDD

Tags: perforce

I have a lot of files within the file structure of the perforce depot that I am unable to see with the perforce clients p4 command line or p4v gui even when logged in as admin.

I have tried to find any meta data I can through p4 files and p4 filelog commands but it always returns:

"- no such file(s)."

Also I have run p4 verify and p4 dbverify to see if there we were any errors on the server but they returned no errors. There just seems to be no records of the files except for the fact that they are taking up room on the HDD.

My current theory is that they are from failed commits but I do not know how to get perforce to acknowledge the files so I can obliterate them.

Background info:

- This is a simple perforce setup with just the main depot and an archive depot for old projects. (The mystery files are in the main depot)
- The server version is: P4D/NTX64/2012.2/551823 (2012/11/09).

Comment: You say you're unable to see them through a Perforce client.  Exactly what are you typing?  Are you using depot paths or local paths?  Are you sure that the view of your Perforce client is correctly configured?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more details. Pick one or two specific examples, and provide all the details. You seem very confused about the basic concepts. For example, you talk about the "client missing files", but then you talk a lot about trying to "obliterate" or "verify" the files, which are actions which only affect files on the **server**, not on the **client**.

Comment: @jamesdlin I am using depot paths for example `p4 files //depot/path/to/files/...`

Comment: @BryanPendleton Sorry if I am using poor terminology, what I mean by the "client missing files" is that when I browse to the location where I expect the files to be in p4v there is no sign of them. I understand that this "file structure" is generated from the meta data and is an abstraction from the actual file structure on the HDD. My issue lies is that I can see files on the HDD that do no appear to be listed in the perforce view.

Comment: @BryanPendleton I should add I am only looking at the depot file structure not the workspace as I am not concerned with local changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't necessarily a one-to-one mapping between what's in the server's depot filesystem and the actual structure of the depot as defined in the metadata -- depot revisions are written once and are not moved or duplicated even if they're moved or duplicated from the point of view of the client.  So you definitely shouldn't make the assumption that because a given file in the depot filesystem doesn't correspond to a depot file path that it's not actually providing the underlying storage for some other existing file (especially if you've used obliterate on some branches of a file while leaving others intact -- the remaining archive file may be the content for one of the ones you left).

That said, it is also possible for archives to become "orphaned" as part of a failed submit as you suggest.  If the amount of space involved is small I'd suggest not worrying about it (the orphaned files won't cause any problems in terms of collisions), but if it's important to be able to clean them up, your best bet is to use "snap -n" to make sure there aren't any of those dependencies and then delete them manually (just to be safe I'd keep a backup of them at least until you've run your next verify to make sure nothing important has gone missing).  Run:

```
p4 snap -n //... //depot/path/to/mystery/file
```

This says "show me files anywhere in the depot (//...) with archive dependencies on //depot/path/to/mystery/file".  If you run the command without the `-n` it will actually break those dependencies by making physical copies (don't do this if you're worried about space since you'll end up with N redundant copies of the archive).

The inverse of `p4 snap -n` (i.e. "where does the archive for this depot file live?") is `p4 fstat -Oc //depot/file`.

Comment: Hi Sam,

This looks very promising.

Yest this abstraction of the files is why I was very wary of just deleting the files from the HDD. I could search for the file by name but I could not see a way to be sure that the files were not renamed.

Unfortunately it was due to the HDD that contains perforce running out of space that prompted this investigation and the mystery files account for over one third of a three terabyte drive. So leaving these files in place is not an option.

Comment: I will try this as soon as I am back in the office. Interestingly p4 snap does not seem to be listed in the [command reference for 2012.2](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.2/manuals/cmdref/index.html) am I looking at the correct documentation?

Comment: Check `p4 help undoc`.

Comment: Cheers Sam. This confirmed that the files are indeed "orphaned" files so I backed them up to another dive just in case and have deleted the copy in the depot. I will now run a verify just to ensure nothing was broken.